# HTTP Status 404 – Not Found From Spring MVC Controller method

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am new to spring MVC and I have one problem. I am creating object of ModelAndView and returing it from the controller method. I debugged it and nothing wrong is in this method, But response is `Not Found` error. (I have tried to return `String` -> "`nameOfjspFile`" and same happens).

this is my project structure:

[image]

This is `SimpleWebConfiguration` Class:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com")
public class SimpleWebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

     public ViewResolver viewResolver(){

         InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver =
                 new InternalResourceViewResolver();

         viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
         viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
         viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

         return viewResolver;
     }


    @Override
    protected void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

this is `SimpleWebInitializer` class:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class SimpleWebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {


    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{SimpleWebConfiguration.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }
}
```

this is `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>GtuMVC</groupId>
  <artifactId>GtuMVC</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>GtuMVC</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://localhost:8086</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!--My Sql driver-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For connection pooling -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Entity, @Table, @Id -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <!--@Controller, @Repository, @Service @Autowired,
    @Configarion, @EnableMVC-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSON data binding -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- XML data binding -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
      <!--added -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
      <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>GtuMVC</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.20.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

This is persistenceManager class:

```
    public class  PersistenceManager {


    private EntityManagerFactory emFactory;

    public PersistenceManager(){
        emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jpa-example");
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager(){
        return emFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void close(){
        emFactory.close();
    }

}
```

this is persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd" version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="jpa-example" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.GtuMVC.Util.PersistenceManager</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="alexander" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />

            <!-- Configuring Connection Pool -->
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="500" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="2000" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

What can be reason of this problem?

Comment: Please, explain the reason of down voting too..

Comment: Attach the controller class too.

Comment: @Selindek can you tell me, what do you mean in it too?

Comment: @AlexanderMujirishvili Check my answer and let us know !

Comment: @AlexanderMujirishvili Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project I changed few things 
First one is Change your package name `com.GtuMVC` to `com.test`
Second, change `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.GtuMVC")` to  `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.test")`
Third, in your controller remove `@RequestMapping("/ui")` and ada a method in controller

```
@RequestMapping("/")
    public String homePage()
    {
        return "accounts";
    }
```

Comment: I will check it when I return at pc and I will notify you what will hapen..

Comment: It seems that I have problem in `emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jpa-example");`, so I will ask another question..